# Force download the pdf file - Angular 6+

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I need to download the pdf file from the URL. I have tried the window.open(URL, 'Download') method but it does not download the file and it opens in the new browser tab.

```
downloadPDFFile() {
     window.open('https://www.w3.org/WAI/ER/tests/xhtml/testfiles/resources/pdf/dummy.pdf', 'Download');
    }
```

Comment: The __default__ behaviour will largely depend on `Content-Type` header that comes with the response. Most of the time this will likely be `application/pdf` which the browser will "helpfully" attempt to view the PDF. You can disable this in Chrome (and I would imagine other browsers) but would be a user preference that you cannot change/override via JavaScript..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import * as fs from 'file-saver';
   
 downloadFile(url) {
            var filename = url.split('/').pop();
            try {
                fs.saveAs(url, filename);
            }
            catch (e) {
                console.log(e)
            }
        }
```